# Air - window resize by + button

Tags: apache-flex, air

When running air application and clicking the windows resize button (+ on a mac) , how is the new size determined? can that be controlled somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try listenting to `resizing` event or `displayStateChange` event and then set your own sizes.

You can also play with maximizible property of NativeWindow(it can't be changed after window is created, however, you can define it initially).